# Script just stops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript script that will hopefully have multiple divs fade in/out every couple of seconds.  Only one will be visible at once.  I've created the following to do the job:

```
var tmnlSpDelay = 5000;
var $currentVis = null;

tmnlFadeIn = function ($re) {
    $re.css("display", "inline");
    $re.fadeIn('slow', "");
    $currentVis = $re;
    setTimeout("tmnlSpinner();", tmnlSpDelay);
}

tmnlSpinner = function () {
    var $random_elem = $('.topcontent').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.topcontent').length));
    if ($currentVis != null) {
        $currentVis.fadeOut('slow', "function() { tmnlFadeIn($random_elem) }");
    } else {
        tmnlFadeIn($random_elem);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    tmnlSpinner();
});
```

As you can see, I'm utilizing jQuery as well to help me.  The problem is after it has ran once and runs `tmnlSpinner` again (except, because it has already run once, `currentVis` is no longer null).  When it runs the fadeOut on `$currentVis`, it just stops working.  Google Chrome isn't giving me any feedback on any kind of error.  Does anybody see any issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `"function() { tmnlFadeIn($random_elem) }"`. You're passing a string where you should pass a callback.